# In git diff, how to exclude root level files

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to get files changed between branches, but I want to filter out root level files, meaning files that aren't in any directory.

These files can be identified by that they don't have / in their path.

I know for example that if I want to exclude some dir I can do

`git diff .... -- :!dir_name`

However, I'm not sure how to add an exclusion to files without /.

Comment: `:!file_name` should work for root-level files. Any problem with that?

Comment: @phd it would work, however I'd prefer a general exclusion rule for future files, so that I want need to change the command every time (it's going to be part of ci/cd pipeline)

Comment: would running `grep -v /` on `git diff --name-only` count ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on Bash on Linux:

```
git diff ':/*/**'
```

These `*` are supposed to be interpreted by Git, not by the
shell. That’s why I’m using single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not insist in how to *exclude* files, you can use

```
git diff HEAD~7 -- '*/*'
```

i.e., you *include* everything that has at least one `/` in the name.

Comment: Since I still need to exclude some files (under some dir) I prefer to exclude. Also this command filtered everything and returned an empty response for me.

Comment: Are you on Windows and are you using CMD? Then drop the single-quotes, because they would be considered required parts of names. Or use double-quotes instead.

Comment: You can still add your additional exclude patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Try the pathspec,

```
git diff -- ':(glob,exclude)*'
```

If the current directory is not the root of the repository, add the signature `top`,

```
git diff -- ':(glob,top,exclude)*'
```

`:(glob,top)*` matches the files in the root of the repository. With the signature `exclude`, it matches the files in the subdirectories.